# Get list of all driving school of a country using google place API, but im able to get only 60 of them using API, any idea what is the issue?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I wanted to get list of all driving school of a country using google place API, but im able to get only 60 of them using API, any idea what is the issue?

OR is there any other API which i can use?

Thank you

Comment: 60 is probably the default limit on objects that you get as a response. Can you specify the API location?

Comment: yeah its like
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=driving+school+in+Germany&key={KEY}